# HBase + Spark : Dataframe put not replacing existing column values with null values for same RowKey

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

We are persisting spark dataframe into HBase.
We are facing issue while overwriting data into hbase, when a column in the updated row is having a value as null, which was not null earlier.

Issue which we are facing is as below:
First we insert a dataframe into HBase as below:

```
val rowsList =Seq(Row("Acct1", "100", "1")Row("Acct2", "200", "2")).asJava

val schema: StructType =
  StructType(List(StructField("a", StringType, true),
    StructField("b", StringType, true),
    StructField("c", StringType, true)))

val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowsList, schema)
```

Then we put this dataframe into HBase, which works as expected.

When we are overwriting an existing rowKey as below:

```
val rowsList = Seq(Row("Acct2", null, "3")).asJava

val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowsList, schema)
```

Then here the value of column 'c' is getting changes from '2' to '3'.
But this row still has column 'b' with value '200'.

How to resolve this issue?